# Contrastive loss in Siamese Network in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, siamese-network

I have been playing around with the contrastive loss of the Siamese network in Keras.  In the original paper, the similar pair should be denoted as `0`, and the dissimilar pair should be assigned as `1`. The contrastive loss should be using this formula:

```py
(1. - y_true) * square_pred + y_true * margin_square
```

However, when I came across the siamese network in `keras.io`, the way they assigned the label and the contrastive loss are [different](https://keras.io/examples/vision/siamese_contrastive/). In their case, similar pair = 1, dissimilar pair = 0, and the contrastive loss eqn is the same as above.

Why does Keras reverse the `0` and `1` in their implementation?

Comment: aren't them the exact same formula?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia, thanks for the reply. Both formula should not be the same right? In the original formula, if similar pair is 0, then D should be activated. However if using the way coded in keras, the one with margin square will be activated. Correct me if i am wrong, thanks!

Comment: It's `similarity` vs `distant`, both work.

Comment: @natthaphonHongcharoen Hi, thank you for the explanation. Can I say that if I assigned similar pair as 1 and use  the abovementioned loss eqn, the output will be the similarity instead of distance? Thank you!

Comment: I usually do that and with cosine similarity instead of distant. This is not Keras but contains all sort of interesting loss function for siamese network. https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/losses

Comment: Primarily with similarity we always know if the value is 0.5 or more it is the same (or cosine of 45 degrees  depending on how you write the code). Whereas distant you have to fine tune the threshold.

Comment: Hi, I just looked at the link that given to you. For the contrastive loss given in your link, the eqn is  loss = (y * D) + （1-y) * max(margin, D）and the label for similar pair is 1, and dissimilar pair is 0. So the output of this way is distance, which is normally less than 0.5. Compared to the keras one, the output should be the similarity, and the higher output indicate higher similarity. Am I right?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen, looking forward to your reply

Comment: Yes higher output indicate higher similarity and `D` is also interestingly default as `1-cosine_similarity` instead of euclidean distant.

Comment: This is also because `cosine_similarity` is easier to draw the line than `pairwise_distant` when you predict. `F.pairwise_distant(target, predict)` may ended up more than 1 anyway despite the loss function really try to keep it to 1.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoeni believe that D stated in the keras code should indicating the Euclidean distance, and I don't see any cosine similarity measure in the code too. Anyway, i believe the output is the similarity. Thanks again!